# Excluding password when extending UserCreationForm

Tags: django

I want to make a view where the user can change the attributes for his User object: first_name, last_name and email address. Django has a built in UserCreationForm for creating users. I already have an extended version that also includes email, first_name and last_name. Now I am trying to extend that one to *not* include the password and username.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
class ExtendedUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 
                  'email', "first_name", 'last_name' )

class UserEditForm(ExtendedUserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
```

The UserEditForm I am looking for will of course not be able to create new instances, but it will only be used to edit existing instances:

```
form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
```

However, the username field and password fields are still shown. How can I exclude these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bad idea to [have a look at a class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L48) you subclass. `password1` and `password2` fields are defined in form directly, not in the model. So `exclude` and `fields` will have no effect on them. Just make your own `ModelForm` as @MatthewSchinckel suggests.

Comment: That must mean that it is in general not possible to subclass a form to remove fields. Right?

Comment: @ThomasWessel You can set them to `None` or some other literal. It will work but would be extrimely bad design. Are you sure other attrs or methods of parent class don't require these fields? Are you sure this removal wouldn't break something? No, you are not sure (and in your case it will break things). So why to go this way?

Answer (score 5):

You can just remove the password2 field in the init of the form like so:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(MyUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['password2']
```

Comment: What about password check? It will accept all invalid password combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a `ModelForm`, and exclude the fields you don't want? That seems like it would be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

think that would give the idea...

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    #first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    #last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    username = forms.CharField (required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','email', 'password1', 'password2')

def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RegistrationForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #remove what you like...
    self.fields.pop ('first_name')
    self.fields.pop ('last_name')
    self.fields.pop ('password1')
    self.fields.pop ('password2')
```

Comment: Why are you using fields.pop() instead of just not defining password1 etc. in fields?