# Django UserCreationForm with one password

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm wondering if I could make UseCreationForm without password confirmation (only password1). Code I'm working with:

```
#forms.py
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

#views.py
class HomeView(View):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Profile.objects.filter(verified=True)
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
        context = {
            'object_list': queryset,
            'form':form,
            'num_of_users': User.objects.all().count()
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

The problem is, that when I make forms.py as that:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1')
```

Form has also field password2. Any solution of that?

Comment: you may try the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39659646/8060120

Comment: its not recommended to use one password field during registration, you should keep password and confirm password so that the user doesnt make a mistake while creating their password

Comment: @Exprator It is misleading to say this is "not recommended."  As of now, many popular sites use a single password field with a "show passowrd" button.  Twitter and Snapchat are two of many examples.  I'm not saying one is better than the other, but it's incorrect to say a single password is "not recommended."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the `__init__()` method of your form and remove the field you want:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields['password2']
```

**Important**: Anyway, it is not a common practice to have only one field for password, because user can mistype it. And security level decreases a lot.

Comment: With Django 2.1, this technically works, but it removes the password validation defined in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 6):

The reason your form has two password fields is because your form inherits two fileds from the parent class, `UserCreationForm`:

```
## Based on actual Django source code
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(...)
    password2 = forms.CharField(...)
```

If you want to remove one of the fields, all you have to do is set it to `None` in your child class.

**However**, In Django 2.1, the default `UserCreationForm` uses `password2` to **validate the password** against the sitewide validators defined in `settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` (source: [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L105))

An easy way to retain password validation, while also removing `password2`, is to set `password2 = None` and define `clean_password1`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation

class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')
    password2 = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1')

    def clean_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        try:
            password_validation.validate_password(password1, self.instance)
        except forms.ValidationError as error:

            # Method inherited from BaseForm
            self.add_error('password1', error)
        return password1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override "password2" with None value.

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password2 = None

    class Meta:
        ...
```